# How to install TinkerPop

Tags: tinkerpop

I have just recently come across graph databases and Tinkerpop.

I am somewhat confused on how/what to install to use Tinkerpop 2.5.0/2.6.0. Does it have to be installed on each Database separately (as you would a plugin) or can I set it up and then use it to access different supported software.

My goal is to use it to try out 2 (possibly more) different databases (mainly Neo4j and OrientDB or perhaps Titan) and be able to query them using Gremlin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could this be off-topic as not be programming related? I'm sure you might get answers from someone knowledgeable in this, but this isn't the kind of question that is generally asked here. :)

Comment: You might indeed be right. However reading through the tinkerpop tagged posts there were similar topics that did not quite clarify things. In any case I thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you use TinkerPop is entirely dependent on what you intend to do with it.  If you are just getting started, I suggest you simply [download](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Downloads) the Gremlin distribution, unpackage it and start the console with `bin/gremlin.sh`.  Working in the REPL will help you learn quickly as the feedback time for trying things out is basically instantaneous.  Even as your Gremlin code makes its way to production, you will find the Gremlin Console to be a good friend as it provides a way to try out ideas before committing them to code.  It also provides a mechanism for maintaining/administering your database with Gremlin.

If you intend to use TinkerPop in a JVM-based application then you will want to use a dependency management tool like Maven and reference the appropriate TinkerPop dependencies you'd like to use.  Alternatively, I suppose you could try to manually manage the dependencies by downloading them individually from Maven Central and adding them to your path (though I wouldn't recommend that for obvious reasons).  I guess my point for suggesting that, is to just make it clear that the TinkerPop library is just a set of jars that can be included in your JVM development tools like any other.

How you work with a particular database is dependent on the one that you choose, but again the process is little different than what I described above.  Neo4j is packaged with the Gremlin Console, so you can work with it right away in there.  For OrientDB, you will want to copy those dependencies into the Gremlin Console path (i.e. the `/lib` directory).  If you are building an application, then maven is again your friend and you simply reference the Neo4j or OrientDB maven coordinates and all require dependencies will come with it.

Some implementations, like Titan, have separate prerequisites (e.g. install cassandra or hbase).  In those cases, you will need to refer to their documentation for specifics on how to set them up.

All that said, if you are just getting started, I recommend that you look into [TinkerPop3](http://tinkerpop.com/).  It is the next major line of development for TinkerPop and quit different from it's previous incarnations.  It does not yet have all the of the implementations in play as of yet, but database vendors are at work to bring them online.  All that I wrote about TinkerPop 2.x "installation" above generally applies to TinkerPop3, however, the TinkerPop3 Gremlin Console does have a [plugin system](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M7/#gremlin-plugins) that can help make it a little easier to bring in external dependencies, preventing you from having to worry about dealing with them manually.

Comment: First of all thank you for the in-depth response. From what I've gathered there is no way (in Tinkerpop2.x) to have a "centralized hub" if you will capable of quickly switching between different databases. I have a followup question regarding the stack in general and Gremlin. By using Gremlin, do you not also use pipes/blueprints?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "centralized hub".  Open the Gremlin Console and you can open an OrientDB database, a Neo4j database, a Titan database, etc. all in one place.  Want to build some micro-benchmarks? Create a maven project referencing all the graphs you like and feed instances of them to your benchmark.  As for your second question, Gremlin depends on both of those things so they are present whether you want them or not.  For most things, you will not code in blueprints/pipes.  It's too low level with respect to writing graph traversals.

Comment: I referred to it as a "centralized hub" for lack of a better word, I suppose a benchmark is a better way of putting it. I now believe most of my problems stem from a lack of familiarity with maven. Thank you again, you have been most helpful.

Comment: As per your instructions I have been using the Gremlin Console 2.6.0 and I have successfully started a Neo4J db in Embedded mode. Am I correct in assuming that it is an instance of neo4j1.9.6 that comes with the package? If so then is there a way to connect to the neo4j 2.2.1 community edition I have downloaded from the official website or must I update/add the package using maven dependencies for the gremlin console?

Comment: yes - it is 1.9.6 as shown in the pom.xml: https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/2.6.0/blueprints-neo4j-graph/pom.xml#L24  if you want to use 2.x then you will have to copy the 2.x jars/dependencies to the gremlin `/lib` directory.  I would delete the 1.9.6 dependencies to prevent conflict.